# passing form input to a script

Tags: html, forms, shell, cgi

I am trying to get input from a html form to pass to a script. i am pretty new at this, but the form simply asks you to enter your name (first & last) then when you hit submit, i am trying to have it return, your name is....

here is my form page

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<p>Please enter your name below.</p>
<form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/test2.cgi">
First:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Last:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo content-type: text/plain
echo
echo your name is $firstnmae $lastname
echo
```

Comment: First, what problem are you encountering? Second, you have a typo in your script (`$firstname`  not `$firstnmae`)

Comment: i get a, page isnt working sever didnt send any data

Comment: Why not use php? also check [\[ this \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802775/how-to-get-post-parameters-from-cgi-scripts-written-in-bash).

Comment: i have never used php, i will look in to it

Comment: @new2coding89 : This question is incomplete without info on server and server settings on handling the CGI script. Check [\[ this \]](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/apache/ch04_02.htm) and good luck.